# Swift setting navigation background image,

Tags: ios, swift

```
class z_main:UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let mainColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 160/255, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = mainColor
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.title = "baosight"
        self.reloadInputViews()



    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }  
}
```

I am beginner ,I hope the code is enough for understanding.

Comment: What's your question? What issue are you having with the posted code?

Comment: I want setting navgatiion background image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "some_name"), 
                                               forBarMetrics: .Default)
```

Comment: Thinks.I want to ask another question,code [self.title = "baosight"] Will change tab bar name .how to avoid？

Answer (score 2):

For Swift 3:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "image")!.resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0), resizingMode: .stretch), for: .default)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[UINavigationBar .appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "img_bg"), forBarMetrics:.Default)];
```